# text not displaying correctly .text should be placed in the center of the screen for the function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display text when a person registers . The next screen shws a rotating spinner with a text "Checking Credentials......" , however the function for it is not displaying the text coreectly in the middle of the screen

```
func rotatingspinner()
    {
        processingView = UIView()

        processingView.frame = self.view.bounds

        processingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 113.0/255.0 , blue: 138.0/255.0, alpha: 0.97)

        processLabel = UILabel()



        let device = Device()


        if device == .iPhone6sPlus {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(145,410,160,30)
        }
        if device == .iPhone6s {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(125,375,160,30)
        }
        if device == .iPhone6Plus {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(145,410,160,30)
        }
        if device == .iPhone6 {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(125,375,160,30)
        }

        if device == .iPhone5s {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100,325,160,20)
        }
        if device == .iPhone5 {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100,325,160,20)
        }
        if device == .iPhone4s {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100,275,160,20)
        }
        if device == .iPhone4 {
            processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100,275,160,20)
        }

        processLabel.text = "Checking Credentials......"
        processLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.0)
        processLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        processingView.addSubview(processLabel)
        self.processingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.center = self.processingView.center
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(processingView)

    }
```

how do i set the screensize.window to the frame and set the frame to keep the text in the middle

Comment: You should really start learning how to use autolayout and abandon this insane path of hardcoding a different frame for every device.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick has said you should start learning Auto layout. Coming to your code, you don't really need to have all that. You need to calculate frame for your label to make sure it is in centre. You can do that in following way

```
let labelHeight = CGFloat(30)
let labelWidth = CGFloat(160)
let labelX = (processingView.frame.size.width - labelHeight)/2
let labelY = (processingView.frame.size.height - labelWidth)/2
processLabel.frame = CGRectMake(labelX, labelY, labelWidth, labelHeight)
```

Comment: the code gives an error that binary operator "-" cannot be applied to CGFloat and Int

Comment: Edited the code. You can convert Int to CGFloat and then subtract